# move_uploaded_file help

Tags: php, file, upload

```
<?php

if (count($_POST)) {

$userfile = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$file_temp = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$path = 'uploads/';

$randomizer = rand(0000, 9999);
$file_name = $randomizer.$userfile;

    if($file_size > 25600) {
        echo 'FILE SIZE TO LARGE<BR />';
        exit();
    }


   if (move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $path.$file_name)) {
        echo '<h3>Upload Successful!</h3>';
    } else {
        echo '<h3>ERROR</h3>';
    }

 }
?>


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
Upload File: <input name="userfile" type="file" /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

I do have a folder named uploads in my root but still this wont work, i dont even get the error. Getting tired..Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off doing something like:

```
if (isset($_FILES['userfile'))
```

In your current code, do you know whether the lines within the "if (count($_POST))" block actually execute? The first thing I would've done is shoved a print_r call (or even just echoed some text) into both the if block *and* created an else block with an echo statement.

It just means you know what it's trying to do, and where it's failing, rather than trying to make guesses at it.